# How can you find and manage items in the Certificate Revocation List using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl-certificate, mmc

Using MMC I can see an entry called `FoobarRootCA` in

```
Local Computer
    Trusted Root 
        Certification Authorities
            Certificate Revocation List
```

But I can't find that entry using powershell. Shouldn't the following return *everything* that is shown in MMC?  It's not showing up.

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\ -Recurse
```

Answer (score 2):

`Cert:` provider in PowerShell supports only certificates in Windows Certificate Store. Mostly, because neither current .NET Framework, nor .NET Core does support managed X.509 CRL classes.

In Windows 10, there is an option to use COM-based interfaces (`IX509CertificateRevocationList` interface and its implementation `CX509CertificateRevocationList` in `X509Enrollment` namespace), but they are not yet documented and do not allow to read CRLs from certificate store directly.

You have to call native CryptoAPI functions ([Certificate Revocation List Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380252(v=vs.85).aspx#certificate_revocation_list_functions)) to read objects from certificate store, decode to a manageable format (standard ASN.1 DER encoded byte array) and then pass to managed implementations. At the moment, these native functions are the only ones to reliable retrieve CRLs from certificate store in code.